# Laravel global helpers vs php helpers

Tags: php, laravel

If there is a global library function and laravel helper that does the same thing. For example, capitalizing first letter in a string which helper should I use? Laravel's or php? And why?

Comment: you mean `ucfirst()`? and also laravel is just a framework, not a language. PHP is the language.

Comment: ucfirst() or Str::ucfirst() for example. And ik the difference between a framework and a language. I just want to know which would be more  preferable. 

Comment: my rule of thumb is to go with PHP first before writing your own custom function or using laravel's helper